# server database isn't displaying on client main.js page

Tags: javascript, html, express, vite

my client main.js file, the code below, is supposed to display the previous entries to the form on the web page,  however when the form is submitted no entries are displayed on the html page, my port is 7777 and the root route works on postman, and so doesnthe post request on the server.js file, this adds an enrtry into the guestbook database. I have created a database through a seed.js file in the server folder,  which can be displayed in my vs code, but won't load in chrome. I will put in my html, my client main.js and my server.js file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. As a user you are supposed to be able to submit a name, date and comment into the guestbook and view the other entries into the guestbook. The front end is done with vite.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script type="module" src="/main.js" defer></script>
        <title>Cold and rainy cottage guest book</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="nav-bar">
          <h4>Cold and rainy Cottege guest book!</h4>
          <form id="form">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
            <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div id="guest-container"></div>
        <div id="new-container"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Client main.js**

```
const form = document.getElementById(`form`);
const guestContainer = document.getElementById(`guest-container`);
const newContainer = document.getElementById("new-container");
//set  base url
const baseURL = `http://localhost:7777`;

//submit  form
form.addEventListener(`submit`, async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // create weird formdata type
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const entryData = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  // fetch response
  const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/guestbook`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(entryData),
  });
  // response  conditionals
  if (response.ok) {
    displayGuests();
  } else {
    console.error("Failed to add guest entry", response.status);
  }
});

//fetches all entries
async function fetchGuests() {
  const guests = await fetch(`${baseURL}/guestbook`);
  //parse into array
  let result = await guests.json();
  return result;
}
// display guests
async function displayGuests() {
  console.log("function workin");
  let guests = await fetchGuests();
  guestContainer.innerHTML = "";
  guests.forEach((guest) => {
    // create guestbook in html
    let h3Tag = document.createElement("h3");
    let pTag = document.createElement("p");
    let commentTag = document.createElement("p");
    let delButton = document.createElement("p");
    let infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let guestCard = document.createElement("div");
    h3Tag.textContent = guest.name;
    h3Tag.setAttribute(`class`, `guestName`);
    pTag.textContent = guest.date;
    commentTag.textContent = guest.comment;
    delButton.textContent = `X`;
    // delete button
    infoDiv.appendChild(h3Tag);
    infoDiv.appendChild(pTag);
    guestCard.appendChild(infoDiv);
    guestCard.appendChild(commentTag);
    guestCard.appendChild(delButton);
    guestContainer.appendChild(guestCard);
    newContainer.appendChild(guestContainer);
    //check if html  was created
    console.log("function ran :(");
    //delete button
    delButton.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // delete function
      handleDelete(guest.id);
    });
  });
}

//delete function
async function handleDelete(id) {
  const result = await fetch(`${baseURL}/guestbook/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
  });
  console.log(result);
  if (result.ok) {
    displayGuests();
  }
}
// call display guests
displayGuests();
```

**server.js**

```
    import express from "express";
    import cors from "cors";
    import Database from "better-sqlite3";
    
    //  variables
    const app = express();
    const PORT = `7777`;
    const db = new Database("database.db");
    //middleware
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
    //listen request
    app.listen(`${PORT}`, () => {
      console.log(`port started on PORT:${PORT}`);
    });
    
    //get request, root route
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send(`root ROUTE ⊂(◉‿◉)つ`);
    });
    //get request at database
    app.get("/guestbook", (req, res) => {
      //try catch
      try {
        //find guest by id
        if (req.query.id) {
          let guestBook = db
            .prepare(`SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE id = ?`)
            .all(`req.query.id`);
          res.status(200).json(guestBook);
          return;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
      if (req.query.one) {
        res.send("Query one");
      }
    });
    //post route to add visitors to guest-book
    app.post("/guestbook", (req, res) => {
      //try catch
      try {
        //set varibles
        const name = req.body.name;
        const date = req.body.date;
        const comment = req.body.comment;
        const newEntry = db
          .prepare(`INSERT INTO guestbook (name , date , comment) VALUES(?,?, ?)`)
          .run(name, date, comment);
        res.status(200).json(newEntry);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      }
    });
    
    // delete
    app.delete("/guestbook/:id", (req, res) => {
      try {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const deletedEntry = db
          .prepare(`DELETE FROM guestbook WHERE id = ? `)
          .run(id);
        //http response codes
        res.status(200).json({ recordDeleted: deletedEntry });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      }
    });
```

**Seed.js**

```
import Database from "better-sqlite3";
//hook up our database.db to get methods
const db = new Database("database.db")
//.exec executes some sql query 
//have to use backticks 
db.exec(`CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS movies (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    movie TEXT,
    year INTEGER ,
    imgURL TEXT)`)

    db.exec(`
    INSERT into movies (movie, year, imgURL)
    VALUES
    ('Black Narcissus' , 1947, 'https://posters.movieposterdb.com/07_11/1947/39192/l_39192_20b67beb.jpg'),
    ('Ran' , 1985 , 'https://posters.movieposterdb.com/23_04/1985/89881/l_ran-movie-poster_0c1ca44d.jpg'),
    ('Day of Wrath' , 1943, 'https://posters.movieposterdb.com/21_09/1943/36506/l_36506_d9d2b6c8.jpg' )
     `)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is in the communication with the DB, in this line

```
app.get("/guestbook", (req, res) => {
  //try catch
  try {
    //find guest by id
    if (req.query.id) {
      let guestBook = db
        .prepare(`SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE id = ?`)
        .all(req.query.id); // <<---.all(`req.query.id`);
      res.status(200).json(guestBook);
      return;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
  if (req.query.one) {
    res.send("Query one");
  }
});
```

You are passing the literal value "req.query.id" as a string, so the ddbb library tries to "Select * from guestbook where id = 'req.query.id'"